# Ensuring Section 508 Compliance of Client File Uploads

Tags: c#, .net, validation, section508

On my companies intranet, the business had asked to allow the users to deposit a file into a shared folder for it to be auto-posted to the intranet site.  Pretty much the same as a file upload, with direct access to the storage device on a different server (with filetype limitations).

Since I don't have any control over the users and their knowledge of Section 508 compliance, is there a method to valid the document prior to it being added to the page? Right now, I have a C# class that builds a list from approved folders within that directory. I just want to make sure that if the files are not accessible, that they do not get added to the list.

Comment: From my knowledge of Ferengi Section 508 I think you need to make sure that the documents are assigned a value in gold-pressed latinum before uploading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry to say that Chris is incorrect in his answer. Section 508 applies to all file types, not just applications. There is a scanner by HiSoftware called [Compliance Sheriff](http://www.hisoftware.com/solutions/hisoftware-compliance-sheriff.aspx), that might work, but it may break due to how big your site is. My recommendation is to train people to make files compliant.

Comment: We currently incorporate a manual process for giving them warning and redirecting them to the business POC's which have instructional media.  This portion of the web site acts very similar to how SharePoint allows authorized users to upload and post files, except it's over the network. With this planned intervention, it would essentially cut out 3rd party scanning software.

Comment: What kind of files are you going to be allowing to be uploaded? MS Office 2010 has a built in checker that does a decent job checking accessibility. Adobe Acrobat Pro has a built in checker as well, but catches the big stuff. Beyond that, you are re-inventing the wheel kind of.

Comment: The primary culprite is Office 2007 (for a short while longer anyway) and Adobe PDF. Ive recommended the business to investigate HiSoftware since I know they are going to be pretty swamped with the number of files available on the intranet site (1k+). Thanks for the scanner recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the files to be truly accessible, then no machine algoritm will do. A story from my previous workplace:

Content editors for a site were asked to enter in a picture's caption (placed below an image, for all to see), and the alt text (for screen-readers). One ended up entering the same text in for the alt text as they did for the caption. As a result, a 508 scan did pass, but an actual 508 evaluation by a human did not.

We had a similar problem as you, with files placed on our CMS. Our customer and her cadre of lawyers ultimately decided that it was not up to the IT staff to determine 508: it was the publisher of the file. If someone wanted to upload a PDF or PPT or Word doc, they had to ensure it was 508 compliant FIRST. We, the code monkeys, were not to take on the risk.

Whenever someone was going to upload a file, we'd warn them about compliance, and offer them a contact for making their files 508 compliant (we had an in-house group for that). We also offered a way for users to flag non-508 files so we could pull them down quickly and get them updated.

Comment: I've been pretty much stressing the same to some of our other developers since business does have a 508 team. Looks like I'll leave it as is and recommend the business use a scanner.